# Rejected App, Watchdog timer or missing entitlement

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So I have an app that has twice been rejected from the app store and I really could use some help!

It has been rejected for the Watchdog timer forcing it to quit when it is first opened. However I have not been able to reproduce this on any of my devices. It does take a long time to build to a device when using xcode (i know that when built from xcode the watchdog is disconnected). But I have a couple questions that might help me fix this.

1. Does the watchdog take into account only `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or are their other methods that it calls?
2. Does the number of frameworks used by the program have anything to do with it? and if so is 11 frameworks just too many?
3. Once the app is installed to a device, and I unplug said device is the watchdog timer re-enabled?
4. What are some other things that can add to the watchdog timer?

Apple said that another possibility could be `Another possibility could be a missing entitlement.` Could someone please explain what this means, I hav'nt seen this before with my other apps but thought maybe it was something new? And does it have to be installed on all apps for the appstore?

**Time Profile for first seconds**

[image]

Comment: AFAIK the watchdog timer is not only active for the startup of an app but also over its entire lifetime. Anything blocking the main thread for too long will get your app killed -> use threading! The number of frameworks in use is not a problem.

Comment: Could you explain to me what threading is? I try to have as little running during the app start up as possible. What about if there are a large amount of image files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are blocking the UI thread for too long. To solve this problem, first you'll need to figure out what code took that long. It might be worthwhile to profile your app. Note that the simulator doesn't emulate the device, it only emulates the API. It could run much faster than the actual device because your computer is more powerful than an iPhone. Try click and hold `Run` at top left of Xcode, and choose `Profile`. Choose `Time Profiler` and run for a few seconds. Stop the profiler to analyze timing in function calls. Note that you may need to dig deeper, find some tutorials or books to really understand profiling.

When you know what parts have been running slow. You can put them into a thread. The easy way would be to use [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html). To get started, visit [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial). You can skip the first half and focus on the actual thread blocks. The APIs are `dispatch_queue_create`, `dispatch_async` and `dispatch_release`.

This will unblock your UI.

Comment: I have added a photo of my Time Profiler after a few seconds. Do you see anything miss here?

Comment: Try checking "Hide System Libraries" at left and re-upload your image. You'll immediately see problems yourself.

Comment: Ok so I think I may have found out where a lot of data was being used up. 229.0ms was being used to run a dictionary check in the AppDelegate.m `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` I have now moved that into my first `viewcontroller` and added it to the `viewDidLoad:` method. Should that free up some start up space, or am I still missing it?

Comment: Nope, you do that, you are still blocking the UI thread. Research Grand Central Dispatch I suggested, and find out how you could put the lengthy operations into a thread. In fact, no matter what you do, without using a thread, you are always blocking the UI.

Comment: Hmmm, ok well i believe that i have reduced the load time for this. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: One more question I had, my application takes a while to build to a device, and i noticed that not all of my applications were the same way, could that also be an indicator of something wrong?

Comment: @JamesDunay, I don't think so. But is it because the resource bundle of your app is large? Without knowing the details of your app, it might be difficult to determine.

Comment: Hi @JamesDunay , after reducing the launch time, did your app get accepted? How did you exactly reduce the launch time? Where did you move the costly operations? Did you use a separate thread? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Do you do a lot of processing in

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,
applicationDidBecomeActive,
applicationDidEnterBackground,
applicationWillResignActive or 
applicationWillTerminate?
```

Things like multiple file access, loading/saving data, synchronous network access can cause your application to freeze on startup or when the user exits, and could cause the watchdog to kill your app.

This Apple Technical note suggests that the watchdog is only looking at the launch, suspend, resume and terminate user interface events, so I would say you should look into these first, and maybe post back some more details of what your app does in the methods listed above.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1693/_index.html

11 frameworks is fine. I have used 11 in an app no problem.

If you start the app up by tapping the icon on the home screen then the watchdog timers will be active and monitoring your app. If you start the app up by hitting run or debug in Xcode, then the watchdog will not be monitoring your app.